# Interpreting physics as boundary conditions in heat equation

Tags: mathematical-physics, heat-equation

I am given a physics problem and I am struggling with interpreting it as a boundary value problem for Laplace equation. I do know how to solve BVPs, but I don't know how to build BVP from a physical problem.

> A two-dimensional rectangular plastine of height $a$ and width $b$
> gives off heat of density $q$. Its right and top sides are
> heat-isolated, and its bottom and left sides are forced to zero
> temperature. Find the stationary temperature distribution.

I can only intuitively suggest that the corresponding BVP is
$$\Delta u = -q \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}, \;\; u|_{y=a} = u|_{x=b} = u|_{x=0} = u|_{y=0} = 0$$

but that's for sure wrong as then the answer is $u=0$ trivially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct boundary condition at $y=a$ and $x=b$ are:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg |_{y=a}=0\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\bigg |_{x=b}=0\\
$$
which imply that there is no conduction of heat across these sides (heat-insulation). The other 2 boundary conditions are as stated.